# Corba Trading Service inspecting tool

Tags: corba, tao

Is there any tool for viewing registered types in CORBA Trading Service, and maybe, for making some simple queries for objects?

I am using TAO, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know off. Maybe you can write your own and contribute it back to TAO. Maybe consider a scripting language for a client, like Ruby with the R2CORBA implementation which is interoperable with TAO

Comment: We recently released an updated 1.4.1 version of R2CORBA which you can easily install as gem, that would make it pretty easy to build such a script.

Comment: Check TAO/orbsvcs/tests/Trading, that is an unit test from which you could borrow a lot of code